# Generate unique ID when adding a row of data to SQL Server database using Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am currently writing an inventory program for my future business. I can already add, delete, update my server.

My problem is that I want to set a unique ID like "ID-0012" or something like that when I try to add the date to my table. Currently I'm only getting ID = 1,2,3,4...

My table consists of ID, Name, Description, Price, Date. I am currently searching for an answer through google, and I have found out that I need to code this in the SQL Server. I tried using uniqueidentifier but I am getting an error of operation type clash.

Comment: Use INT IDENTITY(1,1) for your ID and format it in the presentation layer.

Comment: Can you be more specific about `error of operation type clash.`?. What do you mean by that? It's been a while since I used SQL-Server but I used to use UUID all the time. Also why isn't a sequential id good enough for you?

Comment: Or, instead of doing it in the presentation layer, you could use a Persisted Computed Column referencing the column with the `IDENTITY` property. `uniqueidentifier` is not what you want you here; it doesn't have a numerical value. [uniqueidentifier (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: create table ProductInfo
(
ID int primary key identity(1,1),
Name nvarchar(50),
Description nvarchar(50),
Price nvarchar(50),
Stock nvarchar(50),
AddedBy nvarchar(50),
DateAdded nvarchar(50),
)

I was using this code in making my code, which I just learned watching tutorial videos. Im just a beginner in programming. I can only understand a little, so if its possible(only if possible, im sorry), a step by step procedure would be a lot of help for me to understand it.

Comment: What you have is fine.  Just use the `ID int primary key identity` as your only key.

Comment: Yes sir I'm using that. But what I'm only getting is ID = 1,2,3,4.... What I'm hoping is somewhat like "ID-0012" when I try to add data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Inventory
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   InventoryId AS 'ID-' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `dbo.Inventory` without specifying values for `ID` or `InventoryId`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Inventory (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `InventoryId` will contain values like `ID-00001`, `ID-00002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

**you can you follow this step.**

> For table create

```
CREATE TABLE Inventory
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   InventoryId Varchar(7),
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

> For Insert Query

```
INSERT INTO Inventory (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES ('ID-'+ right('0000'+CONVERT(varchar(7), (cast(right((select isnull(InventoryId,0)  from Inventory where ID=(select max(ID) Form Inventory)),4) as int)+1)),4), Val2, ....., ValN)
```